# Program crashes - Memory leak Detected, and i have no idea why

Tags: visual-studio-2012, crash, command-line-arguments, release-mode

its seems it was all about memory leak, I have used the function `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();`
before and after `malloc` function.
before the malloc I get nothing, and when `_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();` runs after the malloc I get the following:

```
 Detected memory leaks!
                Dumping objects ->
                c:\users\omers66\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\assigment4\assigment4         \assignment4.c(150) : {66} normal block at 0x00F57338, 20 bytes long.
                Data: <                > CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD CD 
                   Object dump complete.
                 The program '[7588] assigment4.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

I guess it means I have an issue with line 150? 
But I can't see anything wrong, here is the code in that section:

```
struct Unit* add_unit(struct Unit* tree, int base, int newId, char*name)
{
    _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
    struct UnitList* tempUnitList;
    struct Unit* temp;
    struct Unit* returnValue = NULL;
    char* helpName;
    if (tree == NULL)
    {
        temp = ((struct Unit*)(malloc(sizeof(struct Unit))));     (line 150)
        _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks();
```

can you see anything wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "command argument"?

Comment: At least provice the code used to _print to txt_

Comment: Project Properties->Debugging->Command Arguments

Comment: And what are you setting in the Project Properties->Debugging->Command Arguments? Please elaborate.

Comment: hey, thank you all, I have updated the post, I think I know the issue, but I can't tell why

Comment: Well `malloc` *is* a memory leak. It stops to be when accompanied by `free`.

Comment: OK, so im wrong again, and this is not the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, eventually It was all an issue with not giving a string enough space with malloc, I forgot to add an extra byte for the '\0' because I used sizeof according to specific string